# how can i add concept of theme or skin to iPhone application

Tags: iphone, themes, skin

how can i add concept of theme or skin to iPhone application ?
my app will download themes from location upon purchase and then it will be applicable to apply that theme to application ..

does apple support any such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Cocoa Touch app, there is no inherent support for visual theming. You're on your own-- a theme will be your defined collection of colors/tinting/backgrounds or whatever is relevant to your app, and you should just apply these to your UIViews, navigation bars, or whatever is relevant.

Comment: suppose i setup in app purchase for themes to unlock, will apple block this way ?

Comment: or how can i dynamically load imaged from internet to my iPhone..where  can i store these images ?

Comment: @abc: They have not rejected other applications for merely changing the colors and style of the overall UI.  However, changing specific elements that they warn you about in the Human Interface Guidelines, such as alert views, can get you rejected because you are reducing the usability of your application.

Comment: @abc: There's nothing *wrong* with defining custom color schemes etc. Most system UI elements accept color tint parameters to alter their appearance. As Brad says, though, don't otherwise alter the rendering of system UI widgets-- you can get rejected for confusion. You're asking about how to dynamically load and store data, though-- that's whole other topic/question that should look up in the docs (see `NSURLRequest` and `NSFileManager`) and then ask separate questions about.